# Can you force Apt to clean before update?

Tags: apt, updates

For a long time `apt update` or `apt-get update` would often hang while getting updates.

The way around it was to spam `apt update` several time until it works. But recently I discovered that if I run `apt clean` before `apt update` apt-get *never* hangs for me.

So of course I wrote myself a script called apt-update and placed it in /usr/bin/apt-update

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt clean && sudo apt update
```

However, this is still a hack and I would prefer to use some established or more elegant solution.

Does apt not support some flag or option to force the equivalent of `apt clean` before getting updates?

Comment: I would be curious why `apt update` would reliably hang. I haven't had an 'update' hang in years....

Comment: network issue maybe? is there some way to diagnose it?

Answer (score 1):

Review the configuration options that can be placed in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`.  There are options to run clean or auto-clean automatically.  See `man apt.conf` for the options.  There is a `Clean` option that should do what you are doing.

In my case I have a setting for Periodic in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic`:

```
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "28";
```